# SetToolTip for property not working in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nsviewcontroller

I have a NSViewController with few NSButton properties.
I'm trying to enable tooltips. Unfortunately my code is not working for the properties but only for the view itself.

For exemple the following code will show only tooltips when I let my mouse on the view, away from the buttons:

```
- (void) SetToolTips {
   [[self view] setToolTip:@"This tooltip is working"];
   [self.myNSButton setToolTip:@"But not this one"];
}
```

Does anyone has an idea why this code is not working?

Comment: Try [myNSButton setToolTip:@"Tooltip goes here."];  If that doesn't work, you should also be able to set tooltips in Interface Builder.

Comment: Did you set or connect `myNSButton` or is it nil?

Comment: Thank you @fbara 
It still doesn't work when I do [_myNSButton setToolTip:@"Tooltip goes here."]; or set tooltips in the IB.
In addition to that, when I move the mouse in the view I get only the view tooltip and not the NSButton tooltip. Enven if my mouse is on it, I still get the view tooltips

Comment: Thank @Willeke for your reply. Yes I connected my NSButton (in the referencing outlets of the IB) and it's not nil

Comment: Does the button tooltip work if you don't set the view tooltip?

Comment: Unfortunately not... Here is some information which could help: I have a master view (MV). Inside MV I add a custom view (CV) and inside this CV I have myView. 
I initialize all these things like this:
[[self.myViewController view] setFrame:[self.myView frame]];
[self.CV replaceSubview:self.myView with:[self.myViewController view]];
where self is the nsviewcontroller of MV.

Comment: @DEADBEEF Are you able to fix this issue?

Comment: @ParagBafna unfortunately no...

Comment: @DEADBEEF I am getting same issue when view is added/visible using addConstraint